# When can you interchange two minimizations of convex functions?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathrm{arg\,min}}$
Suppose $f: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$ is a convex function, and suppose $C = B_2^n$, the (closed) unit ball in the Euclidean norm in $\mathbf{R}^n$. Let $P_C$ denote the projection operator onto $C$. When is it true that 
$$
\argmin_{x \in C}~f(x) = P_C(\argmin_{x \in \mathbf{R}^n}~f(x))? 
$$
In particular I'm interested in necessary and sufficient conditions for this to hold. A sufficient condition, is clearly that $\argmin_{x \in \mathbf{R}^n} f(x) \in C$. But can we do better?

A more general question is what about other sets $C$ which are not the unit ball.

Comment: I'm curious why you are asking. Surely you understand it must be an exceptional case. There is certainly no reason to believe it will be true in general, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, because it is not always true, but it happens to be, for example if $f(x)$ is the Trust region objective, and the constraint set is (any scaling of) the unit sphere/closed unit ball.

Comment: But is that really true in that case? I find that hard to believe. It makes the trust region subproblem far easier to solve than I think it really is. If you have a reference backing that claim I would appreciate it.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I actually misremembered the claim, because first of all, $f(x)$ is not even (typically) convex for TR. What is much more believable, and in fact true (you can verify this w/Lagrange duality) is the listed claim for the linearization around $y$ (which is obviously convex), i.e., $g(x) = f(y) + \nabla f(y)^T(x - y) + \frac{1}{2\eta} \|x - y\|_2^2$ (for $f$, the trust region objective, $y$ your favorite point).

Comment: OK but that’s not a projection as in your question, that’s a prox minimization. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Michael, it is exactly an instance of my question (take $C = \mathbf{S}^{n-1}$, take $f = g$, in the notation of the question).

Comment: I'm afraid not. $P_C$ refers to a projection. That is, $P_C(\mathop{\textrm{arg min}_x f(x)} = \mathop{\textrm{arg min}}_{x\in C} \|x-\mathop{\textrm{arg min}}_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)\|$. Where does $\eta$ figure in to the construction in your original questions, for instance?